# I Want to execute Regular expression using beanshell preprocessor in Jemeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, beanshell

Here is the code i have written,

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String pStr ="Review Required";

int count = 50

for(int i=0;i<count;i++) 
{
String tmp = "wireReviewApprove:headerTable:0:wireStatusValue">\(\.\+\?\)<\/span>";
Pattern patternN = Pattern.compile(tmp);
Matcher matcher = patternN.matcher(pStr);

if (matcher.find())
    {
sampler.addArgument("selectedItemId["+i+"]","true");
    }
}
```

It is giving error :ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `import java.util.regex.*; import java.util.regex.Matcher; import java.util.reg . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 14, column 64.  Encountered: "\\" (92), after : "" 
2015/07/14 08:15:15 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of:`  import java.util.regex.*; import java.util.regex.Matcher; import java.util.reg . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 14, column 64.  Encountered: "\" (92), after : ""

Can any one help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: \\ is not working in above code.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i execute any basic regular expression using beanshell in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

1. Missing semicolon after `int count = 50`
2. Issues with escaping your `tmp` string. If the original looks as:

   ```
   wireReviewApprove:headerTable:0:wireStatusValue">\(\.\+\?\)<\/span>
   ```

   You need to make it look like:

   ```
   String tmp = "wireReviewApprove:headerTable:0:wireStatusValue\">\\(\\.\\+\\?\\)<\\/span>";
   ```

Full Beanshell code:

```
int count = 50;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    String tmp = "wireReviewApprove:headerTable:0:wireStatusValue\">\\(\\.\\+\\?\\)<\\/span>";        
    Pattern patternN = Pattern.compile(tmp);
    Matcher matcher = patternN.matcher(pStr);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        sampler.addArgument("selectedItemId[" + i + "]", "true");
    }
}
```

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.

N.B. It would be better to switch to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and Groovy language as in case of large loads Beanshell can be a bottleneck.